# D3.js get data index of shape on mouseover event

Tags: d3.js

I am attempting to access the data index of a shape on mouseover so that I can control the behavior of the shape based on the index.

Lets say that this block of code lays out 5 rect in a vertical line based on some data.

```
var g_box = svg
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(controls)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function (d,i){
        return "translate("+(width - 100)+","+((controlBoxSize+5)+i*(controlBoxSize+ 5))+")"
      })
      .attr("class", "controls");

    g_box
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "control")
      .attr("width", 15)
      .attr("height", 15)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "#b8b9bc");
```

When we mouseover rect 3, it transitions to double size.

```
g_box.selectAll("rect")
  .on("mouseover", function(d){
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("width", controlBoxSize*2)
        .attr("height", controlBoxSize*2);
      var additionalOffset = controlBoxSize*2;
      g_box
        .attr("transform", function (d,i){
          if( i > this.index) {       // want to do something like this, what to use for "this.index"?
          return "translate("+(width - 100)+","+((controlBoxSize+5)+i*(controlBoxSize+5)+additionalOffset)+")"
          } else {
          return "translate("+(width - 100)+","+((controlBoxSize+5)+i*(controlBoxSize+5))+")"
          }
        })
    })
```

What I want to do is move rect 4 and 5 on mouseover so they slide out of the way and do not overlap rect 3 which is expanding.

So is there a way to detect the data index "i" of "this" rect in my mouseover event so that I could implement some logic to adjust the translate() of the other rect accordingly?

Comment: Is it something like this https://bl.ocks.org/TheBiro/4559617c0ff283e786aea95b194d1fd2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the index of any selection with the second argument of the anonymous function.

The problem here, however, is that you're trying to get the index in an anonymous function which is itself inside the event handler, and this won't work.

Thus, get the index in the event handler...

```
selection.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    //index here ---------------------^
```

... and, inside the inner anonymous function, get the index again, using different parameter name, comparing them:

```
innerSelection.attr("transform", function(e, j) {
    //index here, with a different name -----^
```

This is a simple demo (full of magic numbers), just to show you how to do it:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(5);

var groups = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

var rects = groups.append("rect")
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return 10 + d * 20
  })
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

groups.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).select("rect").transition()
    .attr("width", 50);

  groups.transition()
    .attr("transform", function(e, j) {
      if (i < j) {
        return "translate(40,0)"
      }
    })
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  groups.transition().attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
  rects.transition().attr("width", 10);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

PS: don't do...

```
g_box.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(d, i){
```

... because you won't get the correct index that way (which explain [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745250/d3-js-get-data-index-of-shape-on-mouseover-event#comment74534023_43745392)). Instead of that, attach the event to the groups, and get the rectangle inside it.

Comment: Has the parameters sent to event handlers changed? When I read the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#handling-events) it says: "[handler being] passed the current event (event) and the current datum (d)"

Comment: Yes, they changed. This answer is from 3 years ago, there has been 2 major versions since then.

Comment: is there a way to get the index now that the event handlers have changed?

Comment: @TimurRidjanovic If you have the current datum, I think you can simply check against the original dataset to know which element it is. `findIndex()` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure d3 passes in the index as well as the data in the event listener.

So try

```
.on("mouseover", function(d,i)
```

where i is the index.

Also you can take a look at a fiddle i made a couple months ago, which is related to what you're asking.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/h1hdet8d/1/

Comment: It's a good suggestion but if I console.log(i) inside that function it is always 0. Perhaps this is because the mousehandler only picks up the one shape that the mouse is over so there is only one item to index over?

Comment: Hmm okay. Can you apply the event listener during the enter selection? Then you will for sure have access to the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index usign `indexOf()`. The second argument in the event `mouseover` it doesn't show the index in numbers, it shows the data info you're working, well, you can pass this info inside `indexOf()` to find the number of the index that you need.

```
.on("mouseover", (event, i) => {
      let index = data.indexOf(i);
      console.log(index); // will show the index number
})
```